# Jinja set variable on link click

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

How can I set a variable set to something when a html link is activated?

For example I have an anchor tag to go to another page. Is there a way to activate a function which changes a variable?

With this variable, I want to open up a new page like: @app.route(/VARIABLE_HERE)

How would I go about setting a variable on a link click then opening the page?
Thanks.

UPDATE 1:

I basically have a global variable named 'topic' which is set to 'maths'. I have an image which when clicked changes the value of 'topic' to 'english'.

UPDATE 2:

I didn't think of multiple users, I'm not advanced in this, I'm still learning. Basically my website is a revision tool. I have a list of subjects with topics. When the user clicks on a topic, a question will appear and the user will answer it. What I'm struggling with is that when the user clicks on the topic, I want them to be directed to the same page for every topic but I'm not sure how I can get that page to identify what topic the user has clicked. I thought by setting a global variable when the topic is clicked then reading that variable inside the questions page would work somehow but like you said, it wouldn't work for multiple users. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a little more information in your question. What do you mean by "set a variable set to something"? Set the variable where? Based on what?

If you want to build a link with a variable, do this:

```
<a href="/{{variable}}">Click here</a>
```

But it depends on what that `variable` is and where it's coming from. Provide more details in your question to get a better answer.

**Edit**: I'm providing a little more information based on the new information you've added to your question. It's hard to give you specific advice here, so I'm going to respond to each of your requirements to try to point you in the right direction.

- "multiple users" and global variables

  - You want to minimize your use of global variables for exactly this reason, you can't have multiple users modifying global variables in your app. It's also difficult to use global variables when your app is running across multiple threads or processes. This is related to the ideas of statelessness and "[share nothing architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_nothing_architecture)", and it makes web apps easier to develop and scale.
- "I have a list of subjects with topics"

  - How are you storing these subjects and topics? In a database? MySQL, Postgres, Mongo, sqlite, etc.?
- "when the user clicks on the topic, I want them to be directed to the same page for every topic but I'm not sure how I can get that page to identify what topic the user has clicked"

  - You need to think about how you're storing this data, what the URLs will look like, and how the user is going to interact with them.
  - This sounds very similar to StackOverflow, so think about how StackOverflow works. Right now we're on a question that is tagged with 'python', and when I click 'python' on this page it takes me to a list of all questions that have that tag. Pretty similar, right?

Let's think about how StackOverflow works.

Here is the basic data model:

```
Question
  id
  title (text)
  body (text)
  date (timestamp)
  has one User (the author)
  has many Answers
  has many Tags

Answer
  id
  body (text)
  date (timestamp)
  has one User (the author)

Tag
  name (text)

User
  username (text)
  password (hashed and salted text)
  ...
```

So, for a very basic StackOverflow clone, I need these routes / URLs to do the following things:

```
POST /question
  create a new Question for the current User
  form input: title, body, tags
GET /question/{id}
  pull the Question from the database, along with the author, any Answers,
  and any Tags
GET /tags/{name}
  pull all the Questions for the given Tag
POST /answer/{question_id}
  create a new Answer for the current User under the given question_id
  form input: body
```

(note that this is just one way to organize the routes)

So before I even start thinking about jinja, python, HTML, flask, making links, variables, etc. I'm thinking about how the URLs look and how the data is going to be written to and retrieved from the database.

I recommend you get more proficient at this step (e.g. by following some tutorials, reading a book on application development, taking an online course / MOOC, looking at some open source code, trying a much smaller project) before diving into the full complexity of building a site like this.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've updated it with more information, I'm not quite sure how else to explain it.

Comment: Ok. A global variable in your python program?

Comment: Yeah that's right, so I can use the variable in another @app.route.

Comment: How does that work when you have two different people using the site? Maybe you want a session variable? Either way, you might need to go back another level and describe the larger problem you're trying to solve. You're trying to build a website that does something?

Comment: I've updated the question once again with more detail, thanks for you response before too. If you'd like to see the code please ask.

Comment: Ok, that makes things clearer. Unfortunately it looks like your question may be closed because it's too broad (I didn't vote that way, it's just how StackOverflow works). I've made one more update to my post with some pointers, but it's hard to give you a complete answer because this site is better suited for specific technical problems and not for general advice or instructions on how to build a website.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the routing provided by flask like its meant to be used.

first setup your topic view:

```
# here the first /topic is the url 
# and the second /<topic> sets a variable "topic"          
# that will be passed to the view function
# so going to url /topic/english, would set the 
# topic variable to english
@app.route('/topic/<topic>') 
def topic_view(topic):
    # then youll prolly get the topic questions from the db? not
    # sure how your implementing this
    questions = TopicQuestionModel.query.filter_by('topic'=topic).all()
```

i think that could be what your looking for, thinking about it just doing `@app.route('/<topic>')` would do the same thing, but the url for english would be just `/english` not `/topic/english`. although `/topic/<topic>` looks a little confusing i think explicitly adding /topic to the url is the better way to go in this case, more readable and understandable in the end.